# How to create an image from a Matrix using opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

I have a matrix `m` filled as below(condensed version). Can you please help me to create a image from it. Such that I want all `10` in the matrix to be in different color.

```
m = np.array([[ 1 0 .... -1 10],  [ 10,0, ..... 0, 10] .... ]])
```

The dimension of this matrix is `x rows and y columns`.

To make it simple, I don't need a color image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = np.random.randint(222, size=(100, 100,3))
gen = np.array(img ,dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('i',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('i')
```

Comment: In python opencv, images are just numpy arrays. So your `m` matrix is already an image, just define image type when creating array: `np.array([[...]],dtype=np.uint8)`. Use `cv2.imshow('image',m)` to display it.

Comment: @zindarod - I tried like you said it plots a black image. Please check my sample code.

Comment: `cv2.imshow('i',gen)`

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
img = np.random.randint(222, size=(100, 100,3))
gen = np.array(img ,dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('i',gen)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyWindow('i')
```